# Linq with optional paramter based on the input given

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

In my Method signatures Id and Descriotion fields are there. I need to handle this in where clause. I need to add them based on the request . Like if Id is not null then Id will be in the where clause. If Description not null based on the provided descrription i need to fetch records. I am using Vs 2022 abd EF Core

```
await _dbContext.MyTable.FirstOrDefaultAsync(cr => cr.Id.Equals(request.FirstId) && cr.IsActive == true) if(FisrtId) is not null

if(FirstDescription != null await _dbContext.MyTable.FirstOrDefaultAsync(cr => cr.Dscription.Equals(request.FirstDescription) && cr.IsActive == true)
```

I want something which satisfies the above.

Comment: Play games with `||` (maybe `&&`) to make it all work in a single expression

Comment: What exactly you want to improve on your existing code? What should happen if both request Id and request Description are null or both not null?

Comment: Id and description are related. so if any one of this will be fine. Both cant be null....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe something like this:

```cs
await _dbContext.MyTable.FirstOrDefaultAsync(cr =>
    (request.FirstId == null || cr.Id.Equals(request.FirstId)) &&
    (request.FirstDescription == null || cr.Description.Equals(request.FirstDescription)) &&
    cr.IsActive == true)
```

- When both `Id` and `Description` are null, only IsActive will be checked.
- When either of them is not null it will be taken into consideration in the where clause.
- If both are not null then both are taken into consideration in where clause.

You can also build the query "dynamically" using `IQueryable`:

```cs
var queryable = _dbContext.MyTable.AsQueryable();

if (request.FirstId != null)
{
    queryable = queryable.Where(cr => cr.Id.Equals(request.FirstId));
}

if (request.FirstDescription != null)
{
    queryable = queryable.Where(cr => cr.Description.Equals(request.FirstDescription));
}

var result = await queryable.FirstOrDefaultAsync(cr => cr.IsActive == true);
```

Comment: When both are null i dont want to execute the query itself. i can add some validation for it

Comment: When both Id and Description are null, only IsActive will be checked. how can i exclude this check....like if any one of id or description available then only isactive flag need to check ...else just return empty result.

Comment: can i add this condition in query itself instead of providing a validation on my controller

Comment: Just use a simple if statement `if (request.FirstId == null && request.FirstDescription == null) { // return empty list }`. You shouldn't make all checks in the query. It may work but it makes code less readable.